# Erro CakePHP Ubuntu

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou com um erro no sistema exclusivamente no ubuntu, quando eu rodo com o apache no windows ele funciona normalmente, mas quando eu mando executar com o apache do Ubuntu ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal Error

Error: Class 'AttachmentBehavior' not found
File: /var/www/html/cake/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php
Line: 169

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors  /fatal_error.ctp
```

Nunca fiz nenhuma modificação neste arquivo, estou sem entender este erro.

Arquivo do erro: http://pastebin.com/cw04y8Xq

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Qual o action de qual controller você está acessando quando aparece este erro?

Comment: Verifique atentamente se caminho, nome do arquivo e classe estão escritos corretamente, lembre que o linux faz distinção entre maiusculas e minusculas.

Comment: Há vários motivos: se você estiver utilizando cakephp + composer, precisa rodar um `composer dump-autoload -o` antes. Caso contrário, deve verificar se o diretório descrito no arquivo `app/webroot/index.php` relativo a lib do CakePHP está correto. No mais, verifique é claro se esse arquivo existe em `app/Model/Behavior/`.

Comment: Pessoal desculpem a demora, o erro tava sendo causado pelas pastas mesmo, renomeei e funcionou certinho.